# Downloading zip from jenkins

Tags: javascript, typescript, jenkins, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm building a VSTS task and i'm trying to download a zip from a jenkins server.  I know my URL is write b/c if i click on the link in the log output (for debugging), it downloads.  I know my credentials correct b/.c i'm able to query the server, and traverse all the build numbers.  Here is what I have up to this point.  The error is when i go to open the zip, i get an unexpected end of file.  If i change `var blob = xhr.responseText` to `var blob = xhr.response` my zip save is only 1 kb (expecting 14,583).  If i leave it to `xhr.responseText` then my download is 27,393 KB.  Documentation says it should be `xhr.response` so what am I doing wrong?

```
export async function DownloadArtifact(build, buildDefName: string, targetDir: string, auth: string){

let requestUrl = `${build.url}artifact/${buildDefName}/*zip*/${buildDefName}_${build.id}.zip`;
console.log(`Download request: ${requestUrl}`);
console.log(`target directory: ${targetDir}`);

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", requestUrl, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "Application/zip");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Basic ${auth}`);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = async function(e){

    let tmpName : string = tmp.tmpNameSync();
    tmpName = tmpName + ".zip";
    console.log(`File Name: ${tmpName}`);

    var blob = xhr.responseText;
    await fs.writeFile(tmpName, blob, function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(`Writing file ${tmpName}`);

        console.log(`##vso[task.setvariable variable=gameZipPath;isSecret=false;isOutput=true;]${tmpName}`);

    });
}

xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Can you look at the contents of the download with a text editor? Sometimes it will turn out to be an actually useful message indicating what error the web server encountered. Other times its just binary nonsense, but worth a shot.

Comment: when assigning the blob to responseText it is binary non-sense with a couple of ANSII characters with the artifact name/path.  When assigning to the response it is just "undefined" written to the file.  So maybe the blob isn't being set when using response?

Answer (score 1):

Is your task intended to be used as a build or as a release task? If it is a release task why not use Artifacts from Jenkins directly?
[image]

Comment: While this would typically be the correct answer, our file sizes are in the realm of 2 GBs and will be passed around locally more than publicly, we don't want to have to download from VSTS everytime when we could just keep it in the network.  But otherwise, yes this is a very good answer

Comment: The agent will download the artifacts from Jenkins so they don't pass through VSTS as far as I know. As long as your Jenkins server and your VSTS agent are in the same network the transfer will effectively be local. I do not see the difference in creating your own download artifacts task vs. using the default one provided by Microsoft. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/JenkinsDownloadArtifactsV1